# What is the reading order for Yoshiki Tonogai's different manga series?

Tags: doubt-tonogai

I can't figure out which I am supposed to read first of Yoshiki Tonogai's manga: *Doubt*, *Judge*, and *Secret*. I know they are all related, but in what order are they supposed to be read?

Answer (score 1):

The order in which they were written is how they are supposed to be read: *Doubt*, then *Judge*, and finally *Secret*.

From [Yoshiki Tonogai's Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshiki_Tonogai):

> Doubt, which was completed in February, 2009, and released in the U.S via Yen Press in April 2013 and July 2013. He is also the artist and writer of Judge, the sequel to Doubt, and Secret, the third in the Doubt series, all connected by the recurring appearance of the iconic Rabbit mask from Doubt.